# CommonJS is synchronous but what would happen if there was a call to an async function

Tags: node.js, commonjs

CommonJS uses a `require()` statement that is synchronous but what if you have a module like so:

```
function asyncFunction() {
    var promise = ...;
    return promise;
}

module.exports = asyncFunction();
```

what kind of problems could arise here? are you supposed to always have synchronous code returned for the `module.exports` object? For example if `module.exports = {}` it will always be synchronous, but in the above case module.exports is a promise, which is suppose is something not considered synchronous. Is there ever a good reason to use requireJS on the server side if you need to import a module that is async by nature?

Comment: Please make your question title a complete sentence.

Comment: Remember the section about titles in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Could you do that?

Comment: There! Now, even though I don't know what the hell the answer would be, it's at least a good title.

Comment: yeah but now i think the title is too long, no?

Comment: Apologies for the late response, but I wrote up [a little query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/307125) to show that even ridiculously long titles can be pretty well-accepted by the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what kind of problems could arise here?

This violates CommonJS conventions and will be surprising to developers. It shows you don't distinguish between code and data. Code in node on the server can and should be loaded synchronously. Data can and should use promises, callbacks, etc.

> Is there ever a good reason to use requireJS on the server side

Not that I've ever seen. Speaking personally, requireJS is terrible and if your module introduced it, there is absolutely no chance I would use it in my node project.

> if you need to import a module that is async by nature?

You'll need to provide specifics. I've never seen a node module that is "async by nature", at least not by someone who understands the difference between code and data and realizes that dynamically loading remote code into a running node.js server application is something most deployments want to avoid for good reasons including reliability and security.

Comment: "Speaking personally, RequireJS is terrible" Could you elaborate on that a little? I've never used it myself, but I'm interested in why you dislike it.

Comment: It's complicated and unpleasant to configure modules to play nicely with it. It's extremely difficult to debug. It requires basically implementation level understanding to get anything nontrivial working with it. You spend your days constantly confused about relative paths vs absolute paths vs URL paths vs "virtual paths" vs nicknames and aliases and all this BS.

Comment: @Peter ...Well then. I'm just gonna, uh, back away slowly from it. And never touch it.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes it's pretty much game, set, match npm at this point. Well over 100,000 modules on npm. All the biggest ones including jquery, backbone, angularjs, on npm now, too. Folks are looking ahead to ES6 modules, webpack, SystemJS, etc, but AFAICT requirejs is clearly being left behind.

Comment: this question doesn't deserve a downvote but one improvement could be to use callbacks instead of promises to illustrate the OP point, however promises make it clearer I think

Comment: Surely require.js is easier to debug on the front-end than Browserify or the like, that puts everything in one big file

Comment: YMMV. I find browserify "just works" and doesn't require debugging, and if it did, a command line node program is easier for me personally to debug but that's highly subjective. I hit mysterious "it's broken. reload the page and everything's fine" issues in requirejs constantly and inconsistent bugs are difficult/impossible to debug for me.

Comment: requireJS is actually pretty good, I think Peter is wrong :) Webpack, Browserify are over-engineered IMO. AngularJS was an excellent framework, and it uses the same DI principles as RequireJS, but RequireJS was even better at asynchronous loading than AngularJS. If you don't like RequireJS, then you are just being dogmatic, or you didn't know what you were doing when you were using it.